# Numpy Error - Only On Linux

Tags: python, linux, numpy, python-imaging-library

The following bit of Python takes two images and performs an 'alpha composite' of them, or in other words, sticks one on top of the other, and returns a single image. The code isn't really something I quite grasp, as it came from another Stack Overflow answer.

```
import numpy as np
import Image

def alpha_composite(src, dst):
    src = np.asarray(src)
    dst = np.asarray(dst)
    out = np.empty(src.shape, dtype = 'float')
    alpha = np.index_exp[:, :, 3:]
    rgb = np.index_exp[:, :, :3]
    src_a = src[alpha]/255.0
    dst_a = dst[alpha]/255.0
    out[alpha] = src_a+dst_a*(1-src_a)
    old_setting = np.seterr(invalid = 'ignore')
    out[rgb] = (src[rgb]*src_a + dst[rgb]*dst_a*(1-src_a))/out[alpha]
    np.seterr(**old_setting)    
    out[alpha] *= 255
    np.clip(out,0,255)
    # astype('uint8') maps np.nan (and np.inf) to 0
    out = out.astype('uint8')
    out = Image.fromarray(out, 'RGBA')
    return out
```

It works great on Windows, but as soon as I move it over to Ubuntu Server, it gives me the following error:

```
File "ImageStitcher.py", line 21, in alpha_composite
src_a = src[alpha]/255.0
IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes (and a single ...) as an index
```

I'm using the same version of PIL and the same version of numpy on both.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: I heard somewhere PIL has support for some things on Windows only... could that be the case here?